# Android SMS verification

Tags: java, android, sms

Hi I developed an android application.. for that a login page I am creating ... I already created code for signup and sign in options now I need a sms verification process in which ... at the time of registration users mobile number is collected and at the time of signup .. an sms is sent from users mobile to the mobile number provided ... and the sms must be a random text.. and the user need to type this text at the time of signup to be successful ... is anyone know how to do this pleas help...
I am providing the code I already developed for the login page....

Main Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


     Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
        btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);



        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);

            }
        });
    }

    public void signIn(View V)
    {
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
         dialog.setTitle("Login");

         // get the References of views
         final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
         final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

         Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);


         btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

                // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


         dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close The Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignIN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:onClick="signIn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignUP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonSignIN"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Sign UP" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

signup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextUserNameToLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:ems="10" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPasswordToLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSignIn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does anybody know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a web service and send the Mobile to web service during signup,

Then use an algorithm to generate a unique code based on the mobile number  and send this code as an SMS to the user

Use the same algorithm in your android app to generate the unique code which is dependent on mobile number

Every mobile number will have only one unique code !!

so these two will match and the user could sign in.

Learn to write a web service  and consume it in your app

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap

http://programmertoolbox.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/communicate-between-asp-net-webservice-and-android-app/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29305/Consuming-NET-Web-Services-via-the-kSOAP-library

Code eg.

```
                    import org.ksoap2.*;
                    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
                    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
                    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
                    import org.ksoap2.transport.*;

                    public class soapclass 
                    {
                    private String[] resultValue;
                    private String res;
                    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/"; //the namespace that you'll find in the header of your asmx webservice
                    String METHOD_NAME= "HelloWorld"; //the webservice method that you want to call
                    String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
                    final String URL = "http://192.168.1.3/Myapp/WebService1.asmx"; //the url of your webservice
                    public soapclass()
                    {

                    this.SOAP_ACTION =NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
                    }
                    public String callHello()
                    {
                    try {

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); //get the response from your webservice
                    res= response.toString();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    res =e.getMessage();
                    }
                    return res;
                    }
```

Comment: thanks ... metalhead..can u give any link of this code...

Comment: do you know to write a web service? and consume it in your android app?

Comment: BO.. Idont know ...can u provide a link ..then it will be useful for me...

Comment: use ksoap2 its very easy,i started with hello world web service and consumed it through my app , once you can do this the rest is easy